# Line through the origin as a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

If $G$ is the group $(\mathbb{R^n, +})$ and $L$ is a line through the origin, $L \leq G$. Can it be proven this way?

(i) Clearly, $L$ is not empty.

(ii) Let $x, y \in L$ be any finite segments of $L$ starting at the origin. Then $y^{-1} = -y$ is the segment symmetric (parallel) to $y$ through the origin, thus $y^{-1} \in L$.

(iii) $xy^{-1}=x+(-y) \in L$, since this is a sum of two parallel segments through the origin.
Thus $L \leq G$.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: That's a sound argument. If desired, one also do a rigorous analytic geometry, for example by using a parametric equations for $L$.

Comment: It is a "line" through "origin". Thus, on that "line", when you are going to add two vectors $x,y$, you will consider parallelogram formed by them with origin, and consider it diagonal; it would again come on "line".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good proof. Well done!

One thing worth pointing out, though, is that you've mixed up multiplicative (*e.g.*, $y^{-1}$) notation with additive (*e.g.*, $-y$) notation. The intent is clear from the context nonetheless, so more credit to you there.

Another thing is that you've used "clearly". Don't. It's much better to say that, since $L$ is a line through the origin, we have $0\in L$, so $L\neq\varnothing$.